# Sample size calculation for a Randomised Controlled Trial

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sample-size, clinical-trials, crossover-study

I know the sample size calculations for a Randomised Controlled Clinical Trial for inferiority, superiority and non-inferiority setups.

But, say I have a Cross-over Randomised trial design with one patient receiving two drugs.
In that case will the size calculation differ in formula or will it be calculated by the same formula as in mentioned for RCT ?

Can anyone mention any software that supports this type of size calculation for cross over RCT ?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.